# retrive data using navigate react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass some data to the next componenet

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

    function toResults(){
        navigate('/results',{results:props.results});
    }
```

But when I am on the next component I don't  have the passed data

```
import React from 'react';


function Result(props) {

    console.log(props.results);
    return (
        <>
            Result
        </>
    )

}

export default Result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

navigate  will look like : `navigate('/results', { state: props.results });`

in Result component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'; 

function Result() {
    const { state } = useLocation();
    console.log(state);

    return (
        <>
            Result
        </>
    )

}

export default Result;
```